# classList.toggle() is not working working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to toggle `#user-profile` but it is not working. Whenever I user click on the `#user-profile-logo`, `#user-profile` div appears and when I click anywhere outside the div, `#user-profile` disappears as visibility is set to hidden. But when I click again on the `#user-profile-logo` the div is not disappearing. For this I used `userProfile.classList.toggle('user-profile-active')` which is not working. Here is the HTML code:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <!-- <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link login-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">{{ request.user }}</a></li> -->
        <li class="nav-item user-profile-view px-2 ms-auto">
            <img src="{% static 'images/user-profile-avatar6.png' %}" alt="" id="user-profile-logo">
            <ul id="user-profile" class="p-0">
                <li class="user-profile-list px-2 py-3" style="border-top-left-radius: 20px; border-top-right-radius: 20px;">
                    <a href="#"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-pencil px-3" style="color: #ff6600;"></i>Edit User</span></a>
                </li>
                <hr class="m-0"> 

                <li class="user-profile-list px-2 py-3">
                    <a href=""><span><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-gear fa-shake px-3" style="color: #ff6600;"></i>Settings</span></a>
                </li>
                <hr class="m-0">

                <li class="user-profile-list px-2 py-3" style="border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;">
                    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-right-from-bracket fa-beat px-3" style="color: #ff6600;"></i>Logout</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link login-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    
    <li class="nav-item nav-cart-item">
        <div class=""><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cart' %}"><img id="cart-icon" src="{% static 'images/cart1.png' %}"></a></div>
        <p id="cart-total">{{ cartItems }}</p>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
script type="text/javascript">
        var userProfileLogo = document.getElementById('user-profile-logo');

        // Get the user profile element
        var userProfile = document.getElementById('user-profile');

        // Add a click event listener to the user profile logo element
        userProfileLogo.addEventListener('click', function() {
            userProfile.classList.toggle('user-profile-active')
        });

        // if user clicks anywhere outside that userProfile 'user-profile' div that div will disappear
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
            if(!userProfile.contains(e.target)){
                userProfile.classList.remove('user-profile-active')
            }
        })

    </script>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
#user-profile{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
    width: 170px;
    left: -60px;
    background-color: #f1d5c5;
    border-radius: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 99999999999999999;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 800ms, opacity 400ms;
}

#user-profile.user-profile-active{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 400ms; 
}
```

I was expecting that the `#user-profile` div disappears when I click on the `#user-profile-logo` or outside anywhere that div. Please review my code and kindly give some feedback
Thank you

Comment: Is the logo outside the element you are hiding? If so the 'outside click' listener `removes` the class and then the logo `toggles` the class thus showing it again

Comment: depending on which one is firing first you could [stopPropogation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on that event.

Comment: You could also either add a second condition to your mouseup listener checking if the target is the userProfileLogo `if (!userProfile.contains(e.target) && e.target !== userProfileLogo) { ...` or check for clicks outside the shared parent element with class `.user-profile-view`

Comment: Thank you `if (!userProfile.contains(e.target) && e.target !== userProfileLogo) { ...` worked for me